# Would Devasena belong to the Kunthala Kingdom in Baahubali The Beginning?

Tags: character, baahubali-the-beginning

The first shot of *Baahubali: The Beginning* shows a map. We start at Mahishmathi and track south and see a "Bandit's Hideout" followed by *Kunthala Kingdom* then *Kunthala's Hideout* and then the waterfall....

So I notice that in the movie we do not see any mention of Kunthala or her kingdom or why she needs to go into hiding. So, seeing as the other character who has not been fleshed out much is Devasena and why she is the way she is, is she belonging to this Kingdom?

Answer (score 5):

In the *Baahubali: The Beginning*, Kunthala's Hideout is the place where residents of Kunthala Kingdom are hiding and trying to free Devasena who is a prisoner in Mahismati kingdom.

This group is led by Pruthviraj who is apparently brother of Devasena as shown in Baahubali The Conclusion. He calls her ***our queen*** when a guy starts to cry after finding his brother, as it seems, Dileep died while rescuing Devasena.

**Him calling her queen obviously explains that she would belong to Kunthala kingdom.**

And now it's also explained in the [Baahubali: The Conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baahubali_2:_The_Conclusion).

> Amarendra falls in love with Devasena (Anushka Shetty), a princess of the Kuntala kingdom (7.5 yojanas in the North from Mahismati) and the sister of the king of Kuntala.